# DropDownList display the first register instead of the selected by customer

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got my dropdownlist which is getting the very first register from my datasource instead of getting the one i've selected when i click on the button. Let me explain my self more clear: If i select f.e: INFORMATICA on my dropdownlist and i click on button and then check on my table, instead of INFORMATICA i'll see IDIOMAS (because that is the first register from my table). Sorry for my ignorance but why is this happening? here is my code:

```
  public void llenar_escuela()
{
    dllEscuela.DataSource = puente2.llenarEscue();
    dllEscuela.DataBind();
    this.dllEscuela.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Seleccion Escuela", "0"));
}

public List<string> llenarEscue()
{
    List<string> escuelas = new List<string>();        
    cn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandText = "select esc_nombre from ra_esc_escuelas";
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        escuelas.Add(dr[0].ToString());            
    }
    cn.Close();
    dr.Close();
    return escuelas;
}
```

And here is how i'm displaying the data in my dropdownlist:

[image]

Here is the event when i click on my button:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        //codigos de las facultades y escuelas seleccionadas y luego obtener codigo
        string facu = Convert.ToString(dllFacul.SelectedItem);
        string escu = Convert.ToString(dllEscuela.SelectedItem);
        string codigo_empleado = (txtCodEmp.Text);
        int anio = 100;

        cod_facu = puente2.getcodigoFacu(facu);
        cod_escu = puente2.getcodigoEscu(escu);
        /**************************************************************************/
        //Insertando el nuevo coordinador
        //msj = puente2.insert_coordinador(Convert.ToInt32(txtCodEmp.Text), txtNomDoc.Text, cod_facu, anio, cod_escu, 1);
        int valor = puente1.inserta_coordinador(Convert.ToInt32(txtCodEmp.Text), txtNomDoc.Text, cod_facu, anio, cod_escu, 1);
        if (valor == 5)
        {
            msj = "Ya existe este coordinador en este ciclo";
        }
        else
        {
            msj = "Coordinador isnertado con exito";
        }
        lblexito.Text = msj;

        //Luego de insertado llenamos el gridview actualizado
        llenar_gridview1();

        txtNomDoc.Text = "";
        txtCodEmp.Text = "";
        TextBox1.Text = "";

}
```

Comment: can you translate in english which objects are which? i can sort of translate the comment in the picture there in that you're saying the table is filled with the first item in the list no matter what you select... is that correct? if so, what code is filling that table? can you post your button click event as well? the button click is the most important missing part i think since it probably fills your table...

Comment: That's right my friend! i just posted the button method.. thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who will have the same problem later here there is a solution and the root of the problem: Thank you to Adriano who actually answered this question...

Solution:
[DropDownList only selects the first value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171623/dropdownlist-only-selects-the-first-value?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You're binding to a query, you also need to indicate which item needs to be selected by some criterion:

```
for(var i = 0;i < this.dllEscuela.Items; i++){
    if(this.dllEscuela.Items[i].Value == YOUR_CRITERION){
          this.dllEscuela.Items[i].Selected = true;
          break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, i'm sorry but i'm not aware of how to use that code in mine. Where can i place your code in my code? after my DropDown is filled? or where? thanks in advance..

Comment: After you bind with `DataBind()`

Comment: OK i just did. What am i gonna get with this?

Comment: Once your dropdown has been populated, this code will loop through each of the dropdown's items, and when you find the one that matches some criteria, it will ensure it is the one that is selected in your dropdown.

Comment: Thank you Chris, it sounds cool, imma use that for another time, but i found the root of my problem, here it is check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171623/dropdownlist-only-selects-the-first-value?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

wherever it is that you are binding your gridview, you simply need to exclude items that don't match the selected item in the drop-down list...

something like this:

```
llenar_gridview1.DataSource = YourDataSet.Where(a => a.facu == Convert.ToString(dllFacul.SelectedItem)).ToList();
llenar_gridview1.DataBind();
```

Now there's still a little bit of information missing in that i can't see where you're binding your GridView, so this is based on assumptions as to what your dataset looks like.

Comment: Thank you Max, well my problem comes right when i select the item from my dropdown, no matter which one i've selected it will always be set with the first one. You see that there's a bunch of items in my drop right? so let's imagine you pick DERECHO ramdonly, when i check on my table it will always appear IDIOMAS which is the first one... can u explain it to me? why is it this happening?

Comment: yes... when you are binding your table, you are not using the selected item to define the items that go into the table itself. that's what you have to do... the table seems to be filled with everything, not just the first item... so you have to remove, from the datasource, the items that don't belong. In your Visual Studio, highlight this code segment: llenar_gridview1() , and then press F12, this will show you how the table is being filled.

Comment: thank you for your precious help but i found the problem my friend: here is a glimpse of what really happened to me today i reference it to you so if one day u have this mismo problema ya sepas how to figure out to fix it!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171623/dropdownlist-only-selects-the-first-value?rq=1

Comment: ohhh... i hadn't read your question like that at all... yes that makes sense: don't bind on page load, otherwise your "choice" will be gone on every postback... or, if you do, only bind on the first pageload (if this.IsPostBack())